# Table not fit in container-fluid

Tags: css

I'm Sorry. it was my mistake. the bootstrap css and sb-admin css that i used was wrong. I replaced it with the same bootstrap css that SB-admin used. thx by the way.!!

I have a table that not fit in my container fluid. On the right side, the table pass through container-fluid - not fit in container.

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
 <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="dashboard.php">Selamat Datang Administrator</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <?php echo $_SESSION["username"] ?> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Inbox</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i> Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="dashboard.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Beranda</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="lapangan.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i> Lapangan</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="jadwal.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-table"></i> Jadwal</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="riwayat.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Riwayat</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">
                            Lapangan
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>No</th>
                                        <th>Nama</th>
                                        <th>Deskripsi</th>
                                        <th>Alamat</th>
                                        <th>No-Telp</th>
                                        <th>Jam Buka</th>
                                        <th>Jam Tutup</th>
                                        <th>Jumlah Sub Lapangan</th>
                                        <th>Gambar</th>
                                        <th>Pilihan</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php
                                    $count = 1;
                                    $tampil = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lapangan ORDER BY id_lapangan");
                                    while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($tampil)) {

                                        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM gambar WHERE id_lapangan = " . $record['id_lapangan'] . ";";
                                        $res = mysql_query($SQL, $link);
                                        $img = '<table><tr>';
                                        if (mysql_num_rows($res)) {
                                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
                                                $img .= "<td><img src='" . $row['path'] . "' class='thumbnail imgTbl'/></td>";
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            $img = "<td><img src='gallery/no-image.png' class='thumbnail'><td>";
                                        }
                                        $img .= '</tr></table>';

                                        echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $count . " </td>
                                        <td>" . $record['nama'] . " </td>
                                        <td style='width: 10px;'>" . $record['deskripsi'] . " </td>
                                        <td>" . $record['alamat'] . " </td>
                                        <td>" . $record['no_telp'] . " </td>
                                        <td>" . $record['jam_buka'] . " </td>
                                        <td>" . $record['jam_tutup'] . " </td>
                                        <td>" . $record['jum_sub_lapangan'] . " </td>
                                        <td>$img</td>
                                        <td> <a href='lapanganUbah.php?id_lapangan=" . $record['id_lapangan'] . "' class='btn btn-success fa fa-pencil'></a>
                                             <a onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Peringatan!!\\nAnda akan menghapus lapangan " . $record['nama'] . "\\nApakah anda yakin?');\"
                                                 href='lapangan.php?id_lapangan=" . $record['id_lapangan'] . "' class='btn btn-danger fa fa-trash-o'></a>
                                        </td>";
                                        echo"</tr>";
                                        $count++;
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is css. it's template SB-admin.

```
body {
margin-top: 100px;
background-color: #222;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    body {
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
}

#wrapper {
padding-left: 0;
}

#page-wrapper {
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
background-color: #fff;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 225px;
}

#page-wrapper {
    padding: 10px;
}
}
```

Could anyone help me? I would highly apreciate it.

Comment: please also provide your CSS code, ideally a jsFiddle demo. But a quick solution might be adding the following code: `table { width:100%; max-width:100%; overflow:scroll; }`

Comment: thx for your attention. it solved.